# syntax and expected output of the query

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join

I am trying to use Left Outer Join in Google Bigquery
I have two tables:

- PROD_REF_VIEW - Master table for SKU list along with Substyles (Parent style)
- BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR - Table contains historical sales data

PROD_REF_VIEW contains all SKU's under a Substyle, whereas, BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR contains may contain all or subset of SKU's under the same substyle.

I am trying to perform PROD_REF_VIEW LEFT OUTER JOIN BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR, where I am expecting all the SKU's from PROD_REF_VIEW should appear and depending on the number of SKU's under the Substyle the row should appear in the output. I will giving an example:

Following are the queries to illustrate an example:

Query from PROD_REF_VIEW

```
SELECT SKU, SUBSTYLE FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.PROD_REF_VIEW` WHERE SUBSTYLE = '432481600_BROWN'
```

The output of the query:

```
Row SKU   SUBSTYLE  
1   432497350 432481600_BROWN
2   432497440 432481600_BROWN
3   432497620 432481600_BROWN
4   432497800 432481600_BROWN
5   432497710 432481600_BROWN
6   432497530 432481600_BROWN
```

Query from BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR

```
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, SUBSTYLE FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR` WHERE SUBSTYLE = '432481600_BROWN'
```

Output of the query:

```
Row SKU     SUBSTYLE    
1   432497350   432481600_BROWN
2   432497440   432481600_BROWN
```

When I am doing Left outer join with PROD_REF_VIEW as Left table:

```
SELECT T.SUBSTYLE SALES_SUBSTYLE, V.SUBSTYLE PROD_SUBSTYLE, T.SKU SALES_SKU, V.SKU PROD_SKU 
 FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.PROD_REF_VIEW` V 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR` T 
  ON (T.SUBSTYLE = V.SUBSTYLE) WHERE v.SUBSTYLE = '432481600_BROWN'
```

Expected Output:

```
SALES_SUBSTYLE  PROD_SUBSTYLE   SALES_SKU    PROD_SKU
432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350    432497350
432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440    432497440
                432481600_BROWN              432497620
                432481600_BROWN              432497800
                432481600_BROWN              432497710
                432481600_BROWN              432497530
```

Actual Output:

```
Row SALES_SUBSTYLE  PROD_SUBSTYLE   SALES_SKU   PROD_SKU    
1   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497530
2   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497530
3   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497350
4   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497350
5   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497440
6   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497440
7   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497620
8   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497620
9   432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497800
10  432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497800
11  432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497440       432497710
12  432481600_BROWN 432481600_BROWN 432497350       432497710
```

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> help me understand where I am going wrong.

You missed `T.SKU = V.SKU` part in JOIN's criteria

So, should be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT T.SUBSTYLE SALES_SUBSTYLE, V.SUBSTYLE PROD_SUBSTYLE, T.SKU SALES_SKU, V.SKU PROD_SKU 
FROM `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.PROD_REF_VIEW` V 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `microstrategy-test-env.ZZ_ROCHIT_MARCUS_SANDPIT.BASE_SALES_SEGMT_MTH_SKU_PHR` T 
ON (T.SUBSTYLE = V.SUBSTYLE AND T.SKU = V.SKU) 
WHERE v.SUBSTYLE = '432481600_BROWN'
```